# eval on responseText fails with SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, xml, eval, domparser, responsetext

I am trying to find a right way to create XML document from responseText. How we will use "eval" here. eval on XML throws SyntaxError.

```
eval("<p>This is test</p>"); --> Will fail

sometimes responseText = "<DATA><static-route><route>0.0.0.0/0</route<nexthop>10.204.247.254</nexthop></static-route></DATA>"
or 
responseText = "testing"

parseData(resonseText)

/*create XML Document from the data response */
function parseData (dataSources) {
   try {
        var values = dataSources;

        if (window.ActiveXObject)
            IE = true;
        else if(document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
            IE = false;

              if (IE)
              {
                var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                xmlDoc.async = "false";
                xmlDoc.loadXML(values);
                //Do more things
              }
              else
              {   
                  **//values = eval('('+values+')');**  //Throws SyntaxError
                  var rpcParser = new DOMParser();
                  rpcDocument=rpcParser.parseFromString(values,"text/xml");
                  //Do more things
               }
        }   
        catch (e) {
            //Reaches here if use eval function.
        }
```

};

Thanks,
Vinni

Comment: And what makes you think you should `eval()` it?

Comment: `eval` **only** evaluates JavaScript. `<p>This is test</p>` is not JavaScript.

Comment: so when exactly eval should be used? If server response is in javascript format?

Answer (score 0):

Eval will only accept valid JavaScript. `<p>This is test</p>` not valid JS

Comment: That `eval` accepts JSON is a bit misleading. E.g. `eval(JSON_STRING)` would throw an error. Lets just stick with *"it accepts valid JavaScript"* ;)

Comment: I understand that eval works only for Javascript literal. Thanks. Also on what server response eval should be used?